# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm using `"eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.1.0",` to keep my JavaScript clean.

My linter is unhappy with what seems to be legitimate code:

[image]

It seems like this might be an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4353). Does anyone have any suggestions for an OCD developer on how to address this in the meantime? Perhaps disabling this rule or otherwise?

Comment: why do you need `{ return ...}` for a single statement? You could use `this.state.todos.filter(filterTodo => filterTodo !== todo`

Comment: The issue page you linked to explains the situation quite well, where is the confusion? It does seem odd that it notates this as an error rather than a warning, though that can probably be configured.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The block statement isn't needed for a single expression.

```
this.state.todos.filter(filterTodo => filterTodo !== todo);
```

Comment: vscode does throw an error for single line expressions as well - https://image.ibb.co/jUzGRx/Screen_Shot_2018_04_27_at_3_10_46_PM.png

Comment: eh, no, it throws a warning. one that you can (and probably should) configure

Comment: Hmmm not sure if more legible.

Comment: @Jonny it isn't any more or less legible. It's just the way it is.

Comment: I think it's less legible. As it doesn't include the `return` word, it's not clear to me that it returns anything.

Comment: @Jonny then you might prefer not using arrow functions at all, if you prefer verbose code over everything else. to each their own, this answer and the question it's for doesn't touch on how "legible" the code is. it's mostly irrelevant.

Comment: When I inline the body, eslint now complains about the maximum line length (max-len). Is there a solution to this without disabling the linter for this line?

Answer (score 5):

If you really don't want to wrap arrow function inside block statement then you can turn off.

```
module.exports = {
  extends: "airbnb-base",
  rules: {
    "arrow-body-style": 0
  },
  "env": {
    "jest": true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To add on Kevin answer, the error is related to your eslint configuration. This said, if `arrow-body-style` option is set to true, OP is correct. An other example would be something like this :

```
    return this.state.greetings.map((name) => {
        return <HelloWorld key={name} name={name} />;
    });
```

Without `arrow-body-style` option, block statement ( `{ return ...}` ) is not needed as per Kevin answer.

This actually open a new question as to which style is more appropriate.

For further references : http://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style